# How to print a vector in plain text in QT

Tags: qt

```
 int b=0;
     QVector<int> z(5);
     for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
     z.push_back(i);
     for(int i=0;i<z.size();i++)
     {
         b=z.at(i);
         QString str=QString::number(b);

             ui->mbox->setText(str);

     }
```

I wrote this code to print a vector in plain text but it just print first row I want to print 
whole vector
not:mbox is a plain textedit

now there is another problem

```
QVector<int> z(5);
     for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
     z.push_back(i);
         QString str;
         for (int i = 0; i < z.size(); ++i)
         {
             if (i > 0)
                 str += " ";
             str += QString::number(z[i]);
         }

         ui->mbox->setText(str);
 }
```

in first for loop when I wrote z.size() I get Qt has caught an exception thrown from an event handler. Throwing
exceptions from an event handler is not supported in Qt. You must
reimplement QApplication::notify() and catch all exceptions there.

and also in second for when I wrote z.size I get 10 output but size of z is 5 as you can see .what is wrog
first 5 output is 0 and then rest is normal like 0 1 2 3 4
but I should have 5 output am I wrong

Comment: If it's about debugging: qDebug() << z;

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting the text for every item in the vector. Construct a QString from the values like this:

```
QString str;
for (int i = 0; i < z.size(); ++i)
{
    if (i > 0)
        str += " ";
    str += QString::number(z[i]);
}

ui->mbox->setText(str);
```